# Calculate slope by pandas timestamp index

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset:

```
dates       A   B   C
2005-01-01  1.0 2.0 1.0
2005-01-02  2.0 1.0 1.0
2005-01-04  3.0 0.0 1.0
```

I want to calculate the slopes based on the timestamp index. This should be the result:

```
slope:
A 0.4
B -0.7
C -0.1
```

I tried this solution:

```
slope = df.apply(lambda x: np.polyfit(df.index), x, 1)[0])
```

But it returns an error:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error is telling you you tried to `apply()` the polynomial-fitting on floats, to the 'Timestamp' string column. So don't :) Either make it the index, or don't include it in the columns passed into `apply()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) Don't `apply()` the polynomial-fitting to the 'Timestamp' string column, only to the float columns A,B,C. So either **make `dates` the index**, or don't include it in the columns passed into apply().

**Make `dates` column your index**:

```
df.set_index('dates', inplace=True)

              A    B    C
dates                    
2005-01-01  1.0  2.0  1.0
2005-01-02  2.0  1.0  1.0
2005-01-04  3.0  0.0  1.0
```

b) Now as to fixing up the `apply()` call:

- you're missing a second parenthesis, and you need a trailing `...), axis=1` to apply your function columnwise.
- also since we changed `df.index` to now be dates not the autonumbered integers 0,1,2, you need to pass an explicit integer range into `polyfit()`.

Solution:

```
#pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.3f}'.format
#pd.options.display.precision = 3
#np.set_printoptions(floatmode='fixed', precision=3, suppress=True)

df.apply(lambda x: np.polyfit(range(len(x)), x, 1), axis=1)

dates
2005-01-01    [-1.9860273225978183e-16, 1.3333333333333333]
2005-01-02        [-0.5000000000000004, 1.8333333333333341]
2005-01-04        [-0.9999999999999998, 2.3333333333333335]
```

(Note: I'm unsuccesfully trying to set the np and pd display options to suppress the unwanted dps and scientific notation on the object returned by polyfit. You can figure that part out yourself.]

---

And here's the boilerplate to make your example reproducible:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = """dates       A   B   C
2005-01-01  1.0 2.0 1.0
2005-01-02  2.0 1.0 1.0
2005-01-04  3.0 0.0 1.0"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df), sep=r'\s+', parse_dates=['dates'])
```